# Tab control class not getting data from login screen

Tags: android, tabs

I have an android app in which when user logs in, the employee ID is transferred from one activity to another. This worked fine normally but when I used tab control for the two activities. The employee ID does not go from one activity to another.
please tell where i go wrong in the tab control class. where do i need to call the function for transferring value from tab control to the next class

**my function for sending data from login screen is**

```
 resp = new JSONObject(result);

                    JSONObject Login1Result = resp.getJSONObject("LoginResult");
                    String strMessage = Login1Result.getString("EmployeeID");
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabControl.class);
                           i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strMessage);
                           startActivity(i);
```

**and i call it my next two classes via**

```
{
                 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                  String strEmployeeID="";
                  if (extras != null)
                  {

                      String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");

                      strEmployeeID = value;
                  }


                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MYCLASS.class);
                i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
                startActivity(i); 


     }
```

**and my tab control class is**

```
public class TabControl extends TabActivity 
{
    public static TabControl mTabControl;
    public static TextView textView;
    public static TabHost tabHost ;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 


        // Android tab

        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, HourlyEntry.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Hourly Entry")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home))
            .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, LeaveApp.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Leave Application")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_giveaward))
            .setContent(intentApple);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);


        //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

the spinner where i use the employee id

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner1() 

          {

          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          String strEmployeeID="";
          if (extras != null) {

              String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
//            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              strEmployeeID = value;


          }


          JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
          try
          {
            login.put("EmployeeID",strEmployeeID);
            //login.put("Password", etCountry.getText().toString());

            JSONObject finaldata = new JSONObject();
            finaldata.put("ProjectRequest", login);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try doing something like this**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          String strEmployeeID="";

         TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hourly");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
            photospec.setIndicator("Hourly Entry");

              if (extras != null)
              {

                  String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  strEmployeeID = value;
              }


             Intent photosIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HourlyEntry.class);
             photosIntent.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
             photospec.setContent(photosIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing data in `Intent` while you are fetching it from `Bundle`.
that's the only issue.

Try Following Code.

```
// To get Data in Tab control class
strEmployeeID = getIntent().getStringExtra("new_variable_name");
```

**Updated Code :**

```
// declare at the top in TabControl class
public static String strEmployeeID = "";
```

Comment: i added this line . this line would fetch it from previous class correct. then how do transfer this to next class

Comment: @tusharnarang now which class.? you want to pass it from login to TabContrl. now in which class you want to pass.? and if you want to use this ID through out the app then better to make it static

Comment: sir actually on page load of other activities i make a request to populate the spinner. so the spinner need employee id so i need it there

Comment: i want ot pass this is in both the classes , i.e hourly entry and leave app

Comment: ya buddy then better to make this ID as static variable in TabControl class. so you can anywhere and as this is unique so it will not change till user logged out or exit of app.

Comment: i added the spinner function how to make it static and globally available to all the classes

Comment: I am new to android can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sir i have updated the code. where i send login.. can you tell how can i now tranfer values from one class to another